# ExtJS7: Anchor tag not honoring ext routes

Tags: extjs, extjs7

If a ext view route is used with anchor tag, clicking on that link always opens a new tab. This force realod entire ext app in new tab. Is there a way to force anchor tag or anchor in html to redire ct to that view instead within app

```
                        {
                            xtype: 'component',
                            autoEl: {
                                tag: 'a',
                                html: 'Some Action',
                                href: '#someroute'
                                class: 'link-some-action'
                            },
                            listeners: {
                              click: function(){
                                console.warn("I AM TRAPPED");
                              }
                            }
                        }
```

OR

```
                        {
                            xtype: 'box',
                            html: '<a href='#someaction' class="link-some-action"> Saome Action </a>',
                            listeners: {
                              click: function(){
                                console.warn("I AM TRAPPED");
                              }
                            }
                        }
```

In both case as illustrated, clicking on element opens a new tab, hence forcing app to load again

Comment: how about to use controller method [redirectTo](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.1.0/classic/Ext.app.BaseController.html#method-redirectTo) instead of link?

Comment: but how do we call that then in custom html or `autoEl`

Comment: so you don't know how to listen to click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case, you should add a listener to el, [here is fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34f2)

```js
Ext.define('Controller', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.mycontroller',

    onElClick:function(){
        console.log("I AM FREE");
        this.redirectTo("test")
    }

});
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    style: "border: 1px solid red",
    height: 100,
    controller:"mycontroller",
    title: "test",

    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'component',
        autoEl: {
            tag: 'a',
            html: 'Some Action',
            href: '#someroute',
            class: 'link-some-action'
        },
        listeners: {
            el: {
                click: "onElClick"
            }
        }
    }]
})
```